# Inconsistency with date in questions / answers list

Tags: support, profile-page, timestamps

When I go to my questions list, the date of the question appears on the RHS.

Take a look at the following image: from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703717/danield?tab=questions)

> [image]

The first question shows the date + year (2012)

The second question was asked in 2013, but the year '13' is not appended, so it actually looks like I asked the question on Sep 29 **2014**

**On the other hand**, when I look at the answers list - the year 13 IS appended.

> [image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703717/danield?tab=answers)

Shouldn't there be some consistency here?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - I clarified the question, it's the inconsistency that I'm talking about

Answer (score 6):

> The second question was asked in 2013, but the year '13' is not appended

Because `September 2014` hasn't happened yet. We show the date without a year if it falls within the last 12 months (give or take a few days to avoid ambiguous dates).

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: But when I go to the answer page the 13 IS appended eg June 6 '13 - see http://stackoverflow.com/users/703717/danield?tab=answers

Comment: What can I say... we are not always consistent.

Comment: I edited my question + title

Comment: why is status-by-design attached to your answer instead of the question:P ?

Comment: @mehow - to keep things inconsistent.

Comment: @Oded any chance it's because the timestamp should be the date of last activity but is actually the date when the answer was posted? Just a wild guess here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not sure there was that much reasoning behind it (might have been the handiest extension method at the time of writing the different pages)...